# Napili template - page column dimension vs images

Tags: napili

I'm working with template Napili in a community, and i have to introduce some images in lightning components. 
What i'm missing, is the dimensions that should have an image based on the number of columns that are present in the structure of the pages.

I need to find which is the right proportion of the images to fit the columns width.

I'm refering to the structure of the following image.

[image]